# didSelectRowAtIndexpath work not prorely

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, didselectrowatindexpath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
NSLog(@"selezione");
SitiViewController *sitoSelezionato = [[SitiViewController alloc] init];
sitoSelezionato.title = [[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
sitoSelezionato.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"URL"]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:sitoSelezionato
                                     animated:YES]; }
```

I'm working with a subclass of UITableViewController, I need the cell to be pressed and pushing a new view controller; I tried out the code I copied and pasted before but something is not working properly... I can push the newViewcontroller only if I select another row.. for example if I click the first row i can push the new view controller if I click on the second row... I've already set delegate and datasource... I can't handle this issue.. any idea to come out of this???

Comment: The question is understandable for me, can you please explain better what's the problem ?

Comment: got the error... I misstyped the method to be called once the user click on the cell... didSelectRowAtindexPath ... not didDeselectRowAtindexPath

Answer (score 2):

You mistook `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` with `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.